# Raspbian won't boot when hard drive is connected

Tags: raspbian, usb, pi-2, power, hard-drive

Not sure if this has anything to do with the make/model of hard drive I'm using, but when I connect my WD MyPassport Ultra to my Raspberry Pi 2 and then reset Pi, Raspbian doesn't load. If I just plug a flash memory stick into the Pi, everything's hunky-dory. What's the deal?

Comment: Do you have `max_usb_current=1` set in `config.txt` or not?

Comment: Most likely a power supply issue. How much current are you supplying the Pi? What's the length of your cable? Are you using a powered USB Hub? Is the drive powered externally at all?

Comment: Nope. As I mentioned earlier, this drive is a **WD MyPassport Ultra**. All hard drives of this ilk get their power from the device they're connected to.

Comment: The drive may be bootable with a boot block for something else.

Answer (score 4):

This is (like most questions involving weird behavior of the Pi) a power supply issue. Make sure you have at least a 1.2A 5V power supply for your Pi, and that may not even be enough, you may want to get a powered USB hub too.

### Ways to tell if your Pi is experiencing undervolt (not enough power):

---

**The red PWR led is off or flashing.** It should be solid all the time on a Pi with enough power.

**In non-headless mode, a splash square appears in the upper right hand corner.** This happens when the red PWR led turns off.

**Spontaneous reboot.** This happens when the board doesn't receive enough power and turns off, which disconnects all USB devices, therefor giving the Pi enough power to boot again. This can start an infinite loop of reboots.

Comment: Not having either of those problems (praise the lord). Just doesn't boot up when I plug a hard drive into it.

Comment: @JeffSeale you wont see these problems because it doesn't get that far. Try a powered hub.